# Sending Attachments with mail in UNIX with mailx command

Tags: shell, unix

I am using below command to send attachments in UNIX :

```
uuencode source_name target_name | mailx -s "logs" "abc.gmail.com"
```

the above commnd is working,but my problem is ,the file is comming in very unreadable format.i:e it is not taking new line from the source file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file probably has Unix line endings and you are trying to view it in an editor on Windows (e.g. Notepad) which does not understand them. Try using a different editor like WordPad, Notepad++ or TextPad.

Alternatively, you can run `unix2dos` on your file first, to convert the line breaks from Unix format (line feed) to DOS format (carriage return + line feed)

```
unix2dos < source_name | uuencode target_name | mailx -s "logs" "abc.gmail.com"
```